# Can Single Node Hadoop Cluster be installed on a system with 1gb RAM

Tags: apache-hadoop

I am trying to learn hadoop, would like to know if for basic single node installation 1gb RAM system would be enough or we need more RAM. It would be helpful if someone can share what other minimum system requirements which I can setup single node setup.
I trying to check on Apache Hadoop site but there is no specific mention of minimum system requirements for installation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/556588) and [this recommendation page](https://docs.informatica.com/data-engineering/data-engineering-integration/h2l/big-data-management-10-2-1-performance-tuning-and-sizing-guideli/big-data-management-1021-performance-tuning-and-sizing-guideline/sizing-recommendations/hadoop-cluster-hardware-recommendations.html) it seems you need more RAM. The only way to know for sure is to just try.